# Как сделать сортировку по полю непосредственно в таблице MySql при помощи PHP

Tags: php, mysql, order

Есть такой SQL-запрос:

```
 SELECT * FROM `goods`ORDER BY `amount`
```

Когда его вручную вводишь в phpMyAdmin, то таблица сортируется по полю. Здесь ОК.

А когда его отправляешь из PHP, то вывод данных сортируется, а сама таблица в базе данных остаётся без изменений. Пример кода:

```php
<?php
require_once '../config/connect.php'; //подключение к БД

// готовим запрос в БД:
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM `goods`ORDER BY `amount`';

// выполняем запрос к БД:
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);

// вывод результата запроса:
$arr = mysqli_fetch_all($result);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($arr);
echo '</pre>';
```

Поэтому вопрос:  как из РНР сделать сортировку таблицы по полю именно в самой базе данных?

Comment: `\`goods\`ORDER` где пробел потерялся?

Comment: Пробел уже нашелся :)  Но вопрос остался.

Comment: Не так понял. Ок. `как из РНР сделать сортировку таблицы по полю именно в самой базе данных?` - расшифруйте что конкретно хотите, добавьте пример как сейчас и что нужно. База данных не должна меняться при сортировке, это "фильтры" которые влияют только на получаемый результат

Comment: Нужно поменять таблицу (предварительно её отсортировав) именно в самой базе данных

Comment: Что это значит, "Поменять таблицу", и в чём смысл? Возможно, вы что-то не так поняли, объясните зачем это нужно ибо это глупости какие-то.. Единственная возможность поменять это truncate + заново всё записать

Comment: `SELECT` — оператор запроса в языке SQL, возвращающий набор данных из базы данных. Каким образом при помощи `SELECT` Вы планировали менять что-либо?

Comment: "Когда его вручную вводишь в phpMyAdmin, то таблица сортируется по полю. Здесь ОК." **Нет, конечно**, просто тебе показывают записи, отсортированные по полю. А как они лежат физически в таблице тебя не должно интересовать в большинстве случаев, этот - не исключение.

Comment: Есть таблица.   Мне нужно из РНР  отсортировать  (или перезаписать) эту таблицу  непосредственно в базе данных так, как это делает SQL-запрос  SELECT * FROM  `goods` ORDER BY  `amount` , введённый вручную с панели phpMyAdmin.

Comment: Данные, возвращаемые запросом "SELECT * FROM goods ORDER BY amount" будут одинаковы и при запросе через phpMyAdmin и при запросе через `mysqli_query`.

Comment: @Slavprog запрос через phpMyAdmin и через mysqli_query делают одно и то же - они только отдают данные, которые "где-то там" хранятся, не более

Comment: Всем спасибо.  Наверное я пошел не тем путём. Отвечая на вопрос  
InDevX "зачем это нужно" :  я создаю форму, в которую  чел вводит перечень товаров. Из этого перечня формируется выпадающий список.  Потом чел должен иметь возможность  упорядочить этот список в нужной ему логике: одни товары разместить вверху списка, другие - ниже. Сохранить это, чтобы при следующем сеансе работы  список появлялся уже в логике пользователя.  Я думал решить это таким образом, чтобы напротив каждого товара он вводил порядковый номер, а потом сортировал таблицу.  Отсортированная табл сохранялась бы в базе данных.